# Windows 7 Pendrive not opening

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

When I double click my Pendrive, it takes me to short cut. When I double click on it, a popup comes:
There was a problem starting 4#TF.ini
The specific module could not be found.

The pen drive does not opens. Can you help?

Comment: Sounds like some autorun program starts executing and fails. What's on the drive?

Comment: Should I follow the Answer given below?

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong. The drive has folders and files. I tried the technique suggested below but it did not work. Can you suggest what should I do. Is it something wrong with Rundll32 Error as I was seeing in another forum. If yes, how can I make the error right.

Comment: No, it probably does nothing. You should [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/831257/edit) and answer my earlier question. Also, what is supposed to be on that drive? Why do you double click it? What do you know of the drive? What shortcut are you talking about? You really should give more information if you want help, we are not clairvoyant.

Comment: Joggen, I am sorry but I am not computer savvy. When you asked, whats on the drive, means what does pen drive contains? So I replied drive has folders and files. I dont know if you meant that by your query.        No, I am no longer getting the shortcut symbol, forget about it. The pen drive opens but I cant find anything inside.

Comment: I think probably you are right when you said something about autorun starts executing and fails. For the antivirus says, Autorun blocked. Do let me know what other detail I can provide.

Comment: @Vembu Can you guide me how to do a spyware check I also do not understand what is Malwarebytes and a rescue boot disk. Can you kindly guide. Sorry for being absolute tech dud.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like your usb stick has software that autoruns when you try to click on it. Instead go to `Computer` area where all the drives are listed, and right click on the usb stick, choose `open`, this will open the drive rather than execute an autorun.